# How to upgrade a part of a package/solution (customwebform, workflow, etc.) without losing list items

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been developing a new SharePoint 2010 package in Visual Studio 2010. This is my first development project in SharePoint so please pardon my use of incorrect terminology.

Within the package/solution there are a couple of Features, a couple of custom web forms, and a workflow for the custom list type which is also within the solution.

To develop and debug I've been simply using the Build > Deploy Solution option from within Visual Studio to build the solution and then it would automatically connect to my sharepoint server and create the custom List, install the features, add the workflow, etc.

But when I want to make a change, say change the color of the text on the custom NewForm (mine is called MyCustomForm.ascx) then I click Build > Deploy Solution it deletes the custom list, deletes the workflow, deactivates and deletes the features and then re adds them all again. Thus I lose all of my list items.

In production if I need to modify the workflow I can't simply do this as we would lose all of our list items. How can I do this?

I've done days worth of research and nothing works. I've looked into:

```
stsadm -o upgradesolution -name SharePointProject1.wsp -filename ...
stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs
```

with no avail. It says everything "works" fine (no errors) but doesn't update the custom MyCustomForm.

I've also tried manually editing the files in:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES
```

to no avail as well. I modify the MyCustomForm.ascx file and refresh the SharePoint site page and it hasn't changed.

Any insight would be helpful. I am doing all development on the server machine that is running SharePoint and have admin access if that helps. Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

The list is deleted because the solution package that you're deploying has the list item in it so Visual Studio is "helping" by making sure that you get the lastest version of everything (even it it hasn't changed)

There are two approaches you can take to over-ride this behaviour

1. Set the deployment model to "No Activataion" this will result in the package being deployed and leaving previously deployed and activated feature in place.
2. Remove the list instance item from the package by double clicking on the Package in the Solution Explorer and then double clicking on the List Instance Item in the right hand pane.

Next time re-deploy the solution you not should have your existing list removed (I'm not 100% on the workflow association behaviour).

Of the two I'd lean towards option 2